# Ejecutar un script en functions.php Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy agregando un formulario a la vista de los productos en Woocommerce, y quiero tomar el valor cuando pulse agregar al carrito de productos.

En functions.php tengo una función que se ejecuta, cuando se agrega el producto al carrito:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'save_custom_data_to_cart', 10, 6);
function save_custom_data_to_cart($cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, 
 $variation, $cart_item_data) {
}
```

Basicamente seria ejecutar un script desde ahí que guarde esa variable y usarla en el codigo php después